# SOT Convergence and Compact Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $E$ be a Banach space, and let $A(E)$ denote the closure of the finite rank opertors on $E$. Let $(S_\alpha)$ be a bounded net of operators on $E$ such that $S_\alpha T\to T$ for all $T\in A(E)$. Then 
 1- $S_\alpha\to I$ in the strong operator topology. 
 2- Use part 1 to prove that $S_\alpha\to I $ uniformly on all compact sets of $E$ .

I'm studying the relation between the existence of bounded approximate identity for $A(E)$ and some properties of the space $E$. In one of the proofs the above fact has been used, I'm trying to see why this is true but I'm stuck. Any ideas please! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any $x\in E$, there exists a rank-operator $T$ with $Tx=x$ (use Hahn-Banach to construct a bounded functional $f$  with $f(x)=1$, and then define $Ty=f(y)x$). Then
$$
S_\alpha x=S_\alpha Tx\to Tx=x.
$$
This shows part 1.

For part 2, let $X\subset E$ be compact. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that the balls of radius $\varepsilon$ around them cover all of $X$. Let $\alpha_0$ such that $\|S_\alpha x_j-x_j\|<\varepsilon$ for all $\alpha>\alpha_0$ and $j=1,\ldots,n$.
Then for $y\in X$, there exists $j$ with $\|y-x_j\|<\varepsilon$ and, for $\alpha>\alpha_0$,
$$
\|S_\alpha y-y\|\leq\|S_\alpha(y-x_j)\|+\|S_\alpha x_j - x_j\|+\|x_j-y\|\\
\leq K\|y_j-x\|+2\varepsilon<(2+K)\varepsilon,
$$
where $K=\sup\|S_\alpha\|$.

Comment: @ Martin Argerami: Thank you very much !